# javascript object node list

Tags: javascript

Where can i get the node list of the Javascript build in objects?

what i mean is : document is object of window , wither the function alert is function of the object window , here is a code to example :

```
var w = "window" ,
gg = "gg" ,
pr = "prototype" ,
ts = "toString" ,
pi = "parseInt" ,
al = "alert";

String[pr][gg] = function(){return window[this[ts]()];};
w = w[gg]();
w[al](w[pi]("0"));
```

i write my code like that , to be difficult to copy & read

to use this code writing technique i need to know what function every object contain and so on , Where i can get the node list of the build in javascript object / functions?

---

secondly , how can i assign "this" as string such as the others , to use it in this line :

```
String[pr][gg] = function(){return window[this[ts]()];};
```

can i have example?

Comment: .. if you write your code like this, then you have earned it all.

Comment: That is incredibly unreadable.

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate your code like that in the first place?

Comment: If you have a question, ask a question. If you have two questions, ask **two** questions.

Comment: You want to write code nobody will understand... then you come ask for help? No. Not a chance in your life will I help you. It's one thing to not know your code is bad, it's another to go out on a mission to make it bad.

Comment: *"i write my code like that , to be difficult to copy & read"* So you're obfuscating, but then you're providing the key to decode your obfuscation? What's the point in that?

Comment: Before you do anything weird in any programming language, you should know it first very well. No offense, but I think you still have a lot to learn regarding JavaScript. Have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). Besides that, I agree with the others, use an existing obfuscator. The guys at Google and Yahoo (and other places) know what they are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your fundamental problem is that you're trying to obfuscate your code by hand; bad idea.  What most developers do instead is write their code manually, then use an obfuscator to generate an hard-to-understand version of their code, which they put on their actual site.  The advantage of this is that your original code remains readable and usable by you.

Also, most obfuscators can do a better job of obfuscating than you can (just read Google's JS; it's way worse than your's), AND they'll minify your code as well, making your site (**edit:** as teresko points out, only slightly) faster for your end user.

Google Closure's compiler, or YUI's compressor are both good minification/obfuscation programs.

Comment: actually the benefits of JS-based compression are quite questionable.

Comment: I'm sure it depends heavily on your code; however if you're going to be obfuscating anyways, the vast majority of cases will be at least some small measure faster compressed than not.  (However, I'll grant that with non-obfuscated code the lowered processing required might make up for the lost download time, for a lot of users; I haven't seen any studies one way or the other).

Comment: Do you really expect the JS compression to be better then gzip ? And keep in mind that JS compression has to be decompressed *with javascript*.

Comment: and do not confuse minification with compression.

Comment: Er sorry, I was mixing my terms too casually.  I meant minification.  And yes I do think un-minified g-zipped code will be smaller (and therefore faster to download) than minified g-zipped code. Now, how much smaller/faster is certainly questionable; I make no claims that this will halve anyone's DL time ;-)  All I'm saying is, if you're going to be obfuscating anyways, you will get some (probably small) speed benefit from minifying while you're at it.  As "proof", I submit that Google minifies their code (though for them I'm sure a couple millionths of a second would be enough to justify it).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds what you're looking for is [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  This allows you to specify what *this* means in a specific function.

```
String[pr][gg].bind(String);
```